# How to ignore "not in index" error in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have `col_list = [ "A","B","C","D","E"]`

My dataframe has column `[ "A","B","X","Y","Z"]`

If I run below code I will obviously get error "not in index" as C,D,E is not there BUT I want code to ignore that and add if any column matches with column in list (here it should add A + B)

```
df = df[df[col_list].sum(axis=1) == 0]
```

I used intersection but it dropped X,Y,Z from dataframe so can't use that.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing both the data and the code that you have written that produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: I am getting `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'`. I think there is an error in your syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Use `reindex` instead:

```
df.reindex(columns=col_list, fill_value=0).sum(axis=1)
```

Or you `intersect`:

```
df[df.columns.intersect(col_list)].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: It should be `intersection` instead of `intersect`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code inside a try block:

```
try:
   df = df[df[col_list.sum(axis=1) == 0]
except IndexError:
   pass # or you can do whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming you want to add a new column containing the sum of specific columns.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([(1,2,3,4,5,)],columns=[ "A","B","X","Y","Z"])

col_list = [ "A","B","C","D","E"]

df["SUM"] = df[df.columns.intersection(col_list)].sum(axis=1)
```

The DataFrame will keep all columns and it will have a new one. No columns dropped.